# How to download to server rather than client a Google drive file converted to PDF?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I am using "The Google Picker API" with asp.net web application to retrieve a file saved in Google drive and convert it to PDF using google export, then I want to save the PDF file to web server
I am getting the download link of Google drive file converted to PDF in this format

*https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**an-id-here***/export?format=pdf*

The link is working fine and I'm getting the file downloaded.

But I want to save the file to my wb server using a http handler which I am calling from javascript
When I send the download link to the Htpp handler, the file saved to the server is corrupted
But when I use a url like this one
http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
the file is saved correctly to my web server

I'm using this code to save the pdf fil into the server

```
Using client = New System.Net.WebClient()
            client.DownloadFile(url, tofile)
End Using
```

My question is:

- is there a way to get url for the pdf file rather then a download link
- Or if not possible, is there a way to save the file into the web server using this download link ?

Comment: Do you need to log in to Google to access these spreadsheets?

Comment: I am using google picker, I can access these spreadsheet without problem, but I want to get url to the file converted to PDF

Comment: Yeah I just wondered if your .NET server code will also need to log into google to have access to these spreadsheets.  If you open one of the corrupted PDFs in a text editor, I wonder if it's a bunch of HTML saying "access denied" - you could check.

Comment: In fact when I change the extension of the file saved with the code above,  to html and open it in the browser I get the Gogle logo with this message "One account for all Google products", the same link used is allowing me to download the pdf file into my local machine, and I'm using chrome with the profile allowed to this google drive account connected. the html file has text box to input the google account, when I fill it, I get the pdf file downloaded ! To summurize, instead of saving the file to the server, I'm always getting a download link to the local machine !

Comment: It seems that saving the PDF requires adding some authentication, the question, is how to pass this authentication to this code ( Using client = New System.Net.WebClient()
            client.DownloadFile(url, tofile)
        End Using)

Comment: Not so easy, unfortunately.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601302/c-sharp-webclient-login-to-accounts-google-com

Comment: Thank you, Do you think this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427559/how-to-convert-blob-url-to-a-byte-array-using-javascript-only can work in my case ?

Comment: I have never built a c# app that logs into google, but I did write one that logs into another server which was kind of similar.  I used the "cookie aware web client" approach that Rob B's answer talks about.  I don't think the approach in the answer you linked is comparable to your existing code.